# Error in Google sign auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am getting error during google sign in authentication. Following is error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.1.
```

I am trying to use get code from offical documentation of firebase.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

How to fix it??

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the Error message:

"Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.1."

Set the 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1' to '16.0.1'.

Also check that you have enabled the authentication in firebase console (not sure which authentication method you use, but enable the one you use).

Comment: Update you question with the new dependencies, error message, the method you use to sign in, and a screenshot of your authentication -> Sign-in method. The information you have in your original question is not enough, if the google-service version solution didnt work.